# How to create a vector of unique pointers pointing at default constructed objects

Tags: c++, initialization, stdvector, unique-ptr

Is there a way to create a vector containing *N* number of `std::unique_ptr<T>`s? *GCC v11.2* shows huge and cryptic error messages so I'm not able to detect the issue.

Here is an MRE of what I was trying to do:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>


// a dummy struct
struct Foo
{
    int m_value;
};


int main( )
{
    constexpr auto rowCount { 10uz };
    constexpr auto colCount { 20uz };

    // a 1D vector of pointers, does not compile
    std::vector< std::unique_ptr<Foo> > vec_1D( colCount, std::make_unique<Foo>( ) );

    for ( const auto& ptr : vec_1D )
    {
        std::cout << "Address: " << ptr << " --- value: " << ptr->m_value << '\n';
    }

    // a 2D vector of pointers, does not compile
    std::vector< std::vector< std::unique_ptr<Foo> > >
        matrix( rowCount, std::vector< std::unique_ptr<Foo> >( colCount, std::make_unique<Foo>( ) ) );

}
```

I think I'm missing something important about `std::unique_ptr` here. Is this error because of the fact that `unique_ptr` is not copy-constructible?

If the above method is not possible, then what could be the alternative?

Comment: The reason for the compilation error is fairly basic and easy to explain. However it's unclear whether you want your solution to be limited to a single constructor call, or whether default-constructing an empty vector and then populating it, with N `unique_ptr`s, using a few more lines of code, will work for you, or not. In any case it's going to require a few more lines of code. A single constructor call won't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line:

```
std::vector< std::unique_ptr<Foo> > vec_1D( colCount, std::make_unique<Foo>( ) );
```

makes use of the following vector constructor:

> ```
>      vector( size_type count,
>              const T& value,
>              const Allocator& alloc = Allocator());
> ```

Which receives a given value and copies it to every element of the vector. From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector):

> 3. Constructs the container with count copies of elements with value
>    *value*.

So you are calling `std::make_unique<Foo>()`, getting a `std::unique_ptr<Foo>&&` back from that call, and passing it to the `std::vector`'s constructor so that it copies it across. **The problem is that that unique pointer is not copyable**.

---

You could though:

- create a vector with a given size, and
- for every element in the vector,

  - **create a unique pointer (one at a time)**, and
  - **move assign** that unique pointer to the vector's element.

The example below uses `std::generate` to fill the vector. Notice that the generator function is returning a `std::unique_ptr<Foo>&&` that is move assignable to each vector's element.

[[Demo]](https://godbolt.org/z/dva9Ed9Tf)

```cpp
#include <algorithm>  // generate
#include <iostream>  // cout
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

// a dummy struct
struct Foo
{
    Foo() : m_value{value++} {}
    static inline int value{};
    int m_value{};
};

int main( )
{
    const size_t count{ 20 };
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Foo>> v(count);
    std::generate(v.begin(), v.end(), []() { return std::make_unique<Foo>(); });
    for (auto&& up : v) { std::cout << up->m_value << " "; }
}

// Outputs
//
//   0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19
```

Comment: I think this is a concise way of doing it. Thanks.

Comment: One thing that I still don't get is why in my method, initializing a vector using `std::make_unique` tries to invoke the copy-constructor, but in your method, the lambda does not do that?

Comment: In your code, `std::make_unique` is called once to generate a value, which is passed to the `std::vector`'s constructor; the vector constructor would try to copy that value `colCount` times. In my code, `std::generate` calls `std::make_unique` once for every vector's element, and directly move assigns the value to the destination.

Comment: Aha, now I get it.

Comment: Great! It was badly explained in my initial answer. I've updated it now.

Comment: Another question that I have is: When initializing the vector like this: `v(count)`, how are the unique pointers constructed? default constructed? I mean are they just null pointers? And then `std::generate` overwrites them by moving the return value of the lambda to each element?

Comment: Also could you please edit your answer and add the method of populating the vector using [`std::back_inserter`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter)? For example first `v.reserve(count)` and then insert to the back of it. Is this method possible?

Comment: I send you a [link](https://godbolt.org/z/qrKrq6KK3) instead. There would be so many different ways to initialize the vector that I don't consider adding them to the answer helpful.

Comment: Very nice. That's what I was looking for.

Comment: Regarding your other question, yes, they are [default constructed (1)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/unique_ptr). They wouldn't own a `Foo` object yet. `std::generate` would call [`operator=` (1)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/operator%3D) on them.